Fix dynamic query indentation automatically by plsql
I want a PLSQL code which can indent my dynamic query in pretty indent format
For example
I have insert statement like this
Insert into emp values ( 1, 2 , 3 );

Now this code need to be indented in below format
Insert
Into
Emp
Values
(
1,
2,
3
) ;
My code works for only few pattern and not for all. Is their any way I can make it work for all scenario and even for SQLoader control file as well.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE format_insert_query (p_query IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_formatted_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_indent_level    NUMBER := 0;
    v_indent_str      VARCHAR2(10) := '    '; -- Each indentation level will use 4 spaces
    v_line            VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_pos             NUMBER := 1;
    v_char            CHAR(1);
    v_prev_char       CHAR(1);
    v_next_char       CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    -- Initialize the formatted query variable
    v_formatted_query := '';
    
    -- Loop through the original query character by character
    WHILE v_pos <= LENGTH(p_query) LOOP
        -- Get the current character
        v_char := SUBSTR(p_query, v_pos, 1);
        
        -- Check for beginning of a new line
        IF v_char = '(' THEN
            -- Increase indent when encountering opening parentheses
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || v_indent_str * v_indent_level || v_char;
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || CHR(10);  -- Add a newline
            v_indent_level := v_indent_level + 1;
        
        ELSIF v_char = ')' THEN
            -- Decrease indent before closing parentheses
            v_indent_level := v_indent_level - 1;
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || v_indent_str * v_indent_level || v_char;
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || CHR(10);  -- Add a newline
        
        ELSIF v_char = ',' THEN
            -- Add commas at the end of each line (except the last one)
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || v_indent_str * v_indent_level || v_char;
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || CHR(10);  -- Add a newline
            
        ELSE
            -- Just append the character to the query string if no special case
            v_formatted_query := v_formatted_query || v_char;
        END IF;
        
        -- Move to the next character
        v_pos := v_pos + 1;
    END LOOP;

    -- Return the formatted query
    RETURN v_formatted_query;
END;
/


Calling in this way
DECLARE

    v_insert_query VARCHAR2(4000);

    v_formatted_query VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

    -- Example of dynamically generated query

    v_insert_query := 'INSERT INTO employees (id, name, salary, department_id) VALUES (1, ''John Doe'', 50000, 10), (2, ''Jane Smith'', 60000, 20);';

    

    -- Call the format_insert_query procedure to format the query

    v_formatted_query := format_insert_query(v_insert_query);

    

    -- Output the formatted query

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_formatted_query);

END;


/


Can you edit the question to treat the output sample like code and ensure that the spacing is precisely what you want? It might also help if you explain why you want to do this. Are you really looking for a pretty-printer or code formatter? Or do you need the code precisely formatted for some specific reason?

Keeping the insert keyword, or at least the into keyword, on the same line as the table  name makes it much easier to find where a table is populated within a large codebase. I often search for into\s+tablename (because I can't trust developers to use exactly one space character). Also the right hand side always seems to me a perverse place for commas, as it becomes harder to spot the start of multiline expressions and adding another item to the end becomes a 2-line edit in the Git diff. Also replacing char with varchar2 is always an improvement.
